# Git Branch Notes

Tags: git, github, version-control

I would like to keep a file in each of my git branches called 'branch.note'(note is a file extension I made a custom vim syntax highlighting for, that allows me to write notes in the fashion that I enjoy) I want to use this file to write notes about that branch and what I am doing on it. I want this file to be tracked locally so when I switch to a branch I can just open my notes file and see my notes for that branch, however I do not want this file to go to remote when I push to origin. My dilemma is that if I put the file in my .gitignore it's not tracked, and won't differ between branches. So really what I'm looking for is a way to ignore that file only when I'm pushing to remote and track it normally on my local machine.

I understand that git has a notes command, but those notes are kept on an individual commit basis, I'd like to have notes for the entire branch, that way I can still have them when I commit my work at the end of the day.

Comment: I'd personally just push the notes to origin. Maybe do a `git rm` to delete the note when I finally merge the branch. The advantages of having the note simply outweighs the "noise" of exposing the note for others to see.

Comment: I don't know if what you ask is possible, but this is kind of what you could use Githubs issue tracker for. Just name the branch with the issue number and write your notes in the issue.